# Function to get a match for attributes in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyquery

I am trying to create a function to reduce what will be a lot of repeated code assigning to variables.

Currently if I do this it works

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
import pandas as pd

d = pq(filename='20160319RHIL0_edit.xml')

# from nominations
res = d('nomination')
nomID = [res.eq(i).attr('id') for i in range(len(res))]
horseName = [res.eq(i).attr('horse') for i in range(len(res))]

zipped = list(zip(nomID, horseName))

frames = pd.DataFrame(zipped)
print(frames)
```

Producing this output.

```
In [9]:          0                  1
0   171115            Vergara
1   187674      Heavens Above
2   184732         Sweet Fire
3   181928            Alegria
4   158914            Piamimi
5   171408          Blendwell
6   166836     Adorabeel (NZ)
7   172933           Mary Lou
8   182533      Skyline Blush
9   171801         All Cerise
10  181079  Gust of Wind (NZ)
```

However to keep adding to this I would need to create more variables like this one(below). Where the only changing part is the variable name and the attribute in this case attr(**'horse'**)

```
horseName = [res.eq(i).attr('horse') for i in range(len(res))]
```

So it would be logical then to DRY and create a function which takes an argument which is a list of attributes

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
import pandas as pd

d = pq(filename='20160319RHIL0_edit.xml')

# from nominations
res = d('nomination')

aList = []


def inputs(args):
    '''function to get elements matching criteria'''
    optsList = ['id', 'horse']
    for item in res:
        for attrs in optsList:
            if res.attr(attrs) in item:
                aList.append([res.eq(i).attr(attrs) for i in range(len(res))])

zipped = list(zip(aList))

frames = pd.DataFrame(zipped)
print(frames)
```

Comment: um... you never use the `inputs` function and it takes an argument that is never used?

Comment: _However to keep adding to this I would need to create more and more of these_..........I don't really understand what do you need to add and where.

Comment: A variable for each attribute to be retrieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
attrs = ('id', 'horse', ...)

 ...

data = [[res.eq(i).attr(x) for x in attrs] for i in range(len(res))]
```

Comment: Wow is there anything a list comprehension cannot do?

Comment: The hard worker here is `operator.attrgetter()`, not the LC.

Comment: Yeah i agree and i am probably going to be using that a lot further in future need to find the module docs and see what other options are there. Great andwer.

Comment: Actually, I don't think this will work. I just noticed that the `attr()` method needs to be called, which this answer does not do.

Comment: So there is no way to give a list to attrgetter ()

Comment: `operator.attrgetter()` is the wrong solution. This needs nested LCs.

Comment: like this not working but can't be far off data = [x for x in attrs [res.eq(i).attr(x) for i in range(len(res))]